# In Place Upgrade Windows server from 2012 to 2016, Does weblogic 10.3.6 compatible with Windows server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, weblogic-10.x

Does weblogic 10.3.6 compatible with Windows server 2016?

I want to upgrade windows server from 2012R2 to 2016 for weblogic 10.3.6

Does weblogic 10.3.6 compatible with Windows server 2016?
I want to upgrade windows server from 2012R2 to 2016 for weblogic 10.3.6